# Additional field settings without creating a new field type

Tags: 8, entities

I'm trying to add 2 options to the field settings of all fields of a particular field type, in this case file field. To add the fields to the form I'm using `MYMODULE_form_field_config_edit_form_alter()` instead of extending the base class so it will work with other modules and I won't need to use a custom field type.

Using ThirdPartySettings to store the data doesn't add it to the base config for the field therefore the settings won't be automatically available to other modules.

e.g.

```
function MYMODULE_form_field_config_edit_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  $field = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
  if ($field->getType() == 'file') {

    $settings = $field->getSettings();

    $form['my_checkbox'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => t('My Checkbox'),
      '#default_value' => isset($settings['my_checkbox']) ? $settings['my_checkbox'] : '',
      '#description' => t('Check to check my checkbox.'),
    ];

    $form['#entity_builders'][] = 'MYMODULE_form_builder';
  }
}

function MYMODULE_form_builder($entity_type, FieldConfig $field, &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
   // What goes here? I can't do $field->set() on properties which don't exists.
}
```

I've tried setting up a schema file as `src/config/scheme/mymodule.schema.yml` but I'm not sure how to extend the relevant settings in `core/modules/file/config/schema/file/schema.yml`.

`base_file_field_field_settings` seems to have the relevant entries I'm wanting to add to. Do I need to add a class or an install yml file?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
$field->setThirdPartySetting('mymodule', 'my_checkbox', $form_state->getValue('my_checkbox'));
```

After you save your field settings, the new third party setting should be available in your field config:

```
third_party_settings:
  mymodule:
    my_checkbox: 1
```

Here is a good article about this: https://www.webomelette.com/drupal-8-custom-data-configuration-entities-using-thirdpartysettingsinterface